# Composite Keys SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, key

I have created a joining table for many-to-many relationship.

The table only has 2 cols in it, `ticketid` and `groupid`

typical data would be

```
groupid    ticketid
20         56  
20         87
20         96
24         13
24         87
25         5
```

My question is when creating the composite key should I have `ticketid` followed by `groupid`

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_ticketgroup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ticketid] ASC,
        [groupid] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Or the other way, `groupid` followed by `ticketid`

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_ticketgroup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [groupid] ASC,
                    [ticketid] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Would searching the index be quicker in option 1 as the `ticketid's` have more chance of being unique then the groupids and they would be at the start of the composite key? Or is this negligible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually create two indexes. Given that ticket IDs are more likely to be unique, the clustered index would be GroupID,TicketID in that order. I would then create a non-clustered non-unique index on TicketID.

The reason being that if you wanted to query based only on group ID, they would logically be contiguous and there would be a block of them. The other index will give you fastest when only TicketID is specified.

I do think it would probably be negligible overall depending on how the data will be queried (i.e. if groupid and ticketid are always provided).

Answer (score 2):

The difference would most likely be negligible.

It is however recommended for SQL Server that the most selective column be placed fist. If a column with low selectivity is placed first, the Optimizer may determine that your index is not very selective and will choose to ignore it. See this [sqlserverpedia.com Wiki Article](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Index_Selectivity_and_Column_Order#Which_Field_Goes_First_in_an_Index.3F) for more information.